# Is it possible to add a drop shadow to an svg image?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I've been doing some research on using svg images and have found quite a few good reads. While I don't have a great grasp on svg just yet, still working and experimenting with it. Most of the information I have found on this applies to basic shapes and a few on images or icon fonts. If I have a custom logo word mark in an svg file format and I am including it in my css as:

```
.logo { width: 230px; height: 230px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(../imgs/logo-01.svg) center no-repeat; }
```

Is it possible to add a drop shadow to the word mark itself so that the lettering has the drop shadow effect?

Answer (score 0):

The answer: yes and no. You can do it using a different approach, not a CSS only approach. In this case, what you're looking for is feOffset filter and support is wide yet not complete.

You can read some SVG Filters Tutorials [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to go in and edit the svg file to add a drop shadow filter directly into the image. Start with the webplatform documentation & tutorials:

http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/elements/filter
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/svg/tutorials/smarter_svg_filters